# break node script with async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, npm, exec

I'm running npm install command for list of modules on Node and have an error about async

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

What is the problem?

```
var fs = require( "fs" ),
    path = require( "path" ),
    child_process = require( "child_process"),
    async = require( "async"),
    modulesPath = "../modules/";

var dirs = fs.readdirSync( modulesPath )
    .filter( function( dir ) {
        return fs.statSync( path.join( modulesPath, dir )).isDirectory();
    });

var install = function() {
    if ( dirs.length === 0 ) {
        return;
    }

    var dir = dirs.shift();
    console.log( "installing dependencies for : '" + dir + "'" );

    child_process.exec( "npm prune --production | npm install", {
        cwd: modulesPath + dir
    }, install );


  };

install();
```

Comment: `async` is not a function

Comment: `return this.async();` what do you think this line will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are treating the `async` variable as if it referenced a function when in reality it references an object:

```
return this.async();
```

You should change the line above so that you call the [appropriate method](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) on the `async` object:

```
return async.methodThatYouWantToCall();
```